# Anonymous users haven't access to list/lib views and all content page - SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, anonymous-authentication

I need to give anonymous access on a specific site collection.

I followed this : http://www.topsharepoint.com/enable-anonymous-access-in-sharepoint-2010
or this : https://www.dynamics101.com/sharepoint-2010-enable-anonymous-access/

It works on all others site collections but on this one I can't go on _layouts/viewlsts.aspx or on all list or libraries views. However i can download pdf files and images if I have the link... I don't find out the problem with this site collection. Can you help me please ?

I tried to break inheritance, doesn't work.
There is no versionning or checked out items.

And I don't find the site collection feature "Limited-access user permission lockdown mode" mentionned here : [Anonymous document library prompts for credentials](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/183406/anonymous-document-library-prompts-for-credentials) don't find out why maybe this is the problem...

I tried : [List set for anonymous but public cannot view](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/87534/list-set-for-anonymous-but-public-cannot-view) but the feature ViewFormPagesLockDown is disabled.

Comment: Solved on : https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/316b542f-3d00-438b-98ba-c19043fc1c41/anonymous-users-havent-access-to-listlib-views-and-all-content-page-sharepoint-2010